# react jest snapshot testing - change directory structure

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

My current structure looks like this

```
- Button
  - Button.tsx
  - Button.test.tsx
```

When I add a snapshot test, by default it creates a __snapshot__directory like so

```
- Button
  - __snapshots__
    - Button.test.tsx.snap
  - Button.tsx
  - Button.test.tsx
```

I would like the snapshot file to be colocated next to the other button files like so

```
- Button        
  - Button.tsx
  - Button.test.tsx
  - Button.test.tsx.snap
```

I have read about a new jest config [snapshotResolver](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#snapshotresolver-string)  but I can't get it working with my react app (which was created using CRA).

If I try and add this to the package.json file, react tells me it only supports a number of jest options, snapshotResolver is not one of them.

I've tried following examples online but I can't get it to work

I have created a jest.config.js in the root of my project which contains

```
module.exports = {
    snapshotResolver: './snapshotResolver.js',
};
```

And also created snapshotResolver.js also at the project root (this is taken from a github issue I believe)

```
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#snapshotresolver-string
module.exports = {
    testPathForConsistencyCheck: 'some/example.test.js',

    resolveSnapshotPath: (testPath, snapshotExtension) =>
        testPath.replace(/\.test\.([tj]sx?)/, `${snapshotExtension}.$1`),
    resolveTestPath: (snapshotFilePath, snapshotExtension) =>
        snapshotFilePath.replace(snapshotExtension, '.test'),
};
```

2 things. Firstly, have I setup the jest config and resolver correctly? Secondly, because I am using CRA, does it ignore the jest.config and use whatever defaults it has?

**Edit**

I found this PR that has been opened since August 2019, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6532

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered, `create-react-app` does not support the `snapshotResolver` config option.

So, unless you eject your project, you will not be able to tweak where the snapshots are stored.